# Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I found [this tutorial that fit](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-store-email-attachment-google-sheet-apps-script-alfred-garrett/) my need perfectly.

Basically read csv from an email and export it to spreadsheet.

I modified it just a bit, but getting an error at the final copy function.

The script can fetch the email and csv attachment, the file successfully uploaded/copied to gdrive folder. Just missing the last step, opening the csv and paste the content into the spreadsheet.

Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property openById on object SpreadsheetApp.
ToDrive @ Code.gs:53
VendorToDrive   @ Code.gs:67

This is the code that I'm running

```
var fileTypesToExtract = ['csv', 'xlsx'];
//Name of the folder in google drive i which files will be put



function file_type(attachment){
  var fileName = attachment.getName();
  var temp = fileName.split('.');
  var fileExtension = temp[temp.length-1].toLowerCase();
  if(fileTypesToExtract.indexOf(fileExtension) !== -1) return true;
  else return false;
}
 


function VendorToDrive(){
  //build query to search emails
  var Googel_Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1fraXrYZ7NL4wGP_FXU8n2V-0jAYE0G8IqB5lfqVr0RA");//spread sheet ID
  var Market = Googel_Sheet.getSheetByName("Deal Stage");
  var Market_Data = Market.getDataRange().getValues();
  var query = 'label:zoho-deal-stage';


  var thread_s = GmailApp.search(query);
  
  

function ToDrive(threads) {
  // var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var mesg = threads[0].getMessages()[0];//get first message (most recent)
  
  var attachments = mesg.getAttachments(); //get attachments
    for(var k in attachments){
      var attachment = attachments[k];
       var isDefinedType = file_type(attachment);
      if(!isDefinedType) continue;
   

        var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
        var file = { 
          "title": attachment.getName(), 
          "parents": [{"id": '1sCtaxcbelLl1OSten_hiJX5JuY95IiCl'}]//Folder ID 
            }; //creates a file 
         
          file = Drive.Files.insert(file, attachmentBlob, {
            "convert": true
          });// Adds File t Drive 

       var fileid = file.getId(); //works

       Logger.log(fileid);
        //Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()));
        var attached_gs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileid);// Attached Google sheet data 

          var data2 = attached_gs.getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
          if( attachment.getName() == 'ID_Deal_Stage_Report.csv'){
            Market.getRange(1, 1, Market_Data.length, Market_Data[0].length).clear();

            Market.getRange(1, 1, data2.length, data2[0].length).setValues(data2);
            
          }

      }

  
}
ToDrive(thread_s);

  
}
```

The execution log said this line is the error

var attached_gs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileid);// Attached Google sheet data

I tried changing fileid with the actual fileid (string) but still gave the same error.

Comment: In your situation, what mimeType of `fileid` of `var attached_gs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileid)` is?

Comment: When I log the fileid it just showing string of the file id (44 digits if im mistaken. Not sure if this relevant but the attachment on the file is csv and trough file.insert it get converted to google doc because of the convert: true option.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `When I log the fileid it just showing string of the file id (44 digits if im mistaken.`, I think that this might not be the mimeType. In order to confirm the mimeType of `fileid`, please check `console.log(DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getMimeType())`.

Comment: Thanks for following up :). Im getting this from the console Info application/vnd.google-apps.document

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Im getting this from the console Info application/vnd.google-apps.document`, I could understand the reason for your current issue. The mimeType of `application/vnd.google-apps.document` is Google Document. Google Document file cannot be opened by `SpreadsheetApp.openById`. This is the reason for your current issue. By the way, what mimeType of `attachmentBlob` is? Please check `console.log(attachmentBlob.getContentType())`. And also, `attachmentBlob` is always CSV data?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks for your reply.

 console.log(attachmentBlob.getContentType()) = I'm getting text/plain from this command.

And yes the attachmentBlob is always CSV, I only want to process CSV and already put function to skip anything else.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the discussions in the comment, I understood your situation as follows.

- In your script, `fileid` of `var attached_gs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileid);` is Google Document (`application/vnd.google-apps.document`).
- `attachmentBlob` of `var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();` is always CSV data. But, the mimeType is `text/plain`.

In the case of `file = Drive.Files.insert(file, attachmentBlob, {"convert": true})`, when the mimeType of `attachmentBlob` is `text/plain`, it is converted to Google Document even when `attachmentBlob` is CSV data. I guessed that this is the reason for your current issue. So, how about giving the mimeType of CSV to `attachmentBlob`? When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
```

#### To:

```
var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob().setContentType(MimeType.CSV);
```

or

```
var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob().setContentTypeFromExtension();
```

- By this modification, the mimeType of `attachmentBlob` is `text/csv`. And, `file = Drive.Files.insert(file, attachmentBlob, {"convert": true})` returns Google Spreadsheet converted from the CSV data of `attachmentBlob`.

#### Note:

- If `attachment` is not CSV data, an error might occur. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [setContentType(contentType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setContentType(String))
- [setContentTypeFromExtension()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setcontenttypefromextension)

Comment: @Garin Su Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.